# how to create a class diagram relations in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am created class diagram in asp.net mvc.

I drag and droped some of the classes in the classdiagram.. now I am seeing all my classes.. 
I have two questions here
1) in the class diagram window I need to show property and property defincation
    ex:  Name   string
         ID      int
something like this
2) how to give the relation to one class to other class in the class diagram..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the Class Diagram Menu choose Change Members Format and select Display Members and Type:

[alt text http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/7311/association.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/7311/association.png)

- Right click on the property and choose Show as Association:

[image]